# Custom directive should pass function to parent scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have a search box which I want to use as a custom directive. This is the code for it :

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
angular.module('searchApp', [])
    .directive('searchBox', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                'btnclick': '&onClick'
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                  });
            });
            },
            templateUrl: 'search-box.html'
        }
    });
})(window.angular);
```

In the link part, I need a function that has some JSON data. And then, a directive should have a controller that invokes that function and passes it to the parent scope.

Please show me code for the link function and the controller.